# What is the correct way to release memory allocated in Emscripten/WebAssembly?

Tags: javascript, webassembly, emscripten

I created a web assembly project (C++) with Emscripten. I am making some tests in JS/C++ to clarify how memory allocation works.
My JS code allocates memory for bytes array (_malloc). Then C++ code gets this memory and makes some modifications. Then JS code receives modified data.

JS

```
let worker = null;

window.onload = function () {
    worker = new Worker('worker.js');
    drawImage();
    const btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
    btn.addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
}

function clickHandler() {
    console.log('clicked');
    //for (var i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
        test();
}
 
function test() {
    const imageData = getCanvasImage();
    const buffer = imageData.data.buffer;
    const bufSize = imageData.width * imageData.height * 4;
    
    const dataPtr = Module._malloc(bufSize);
    const dataOnHeap = new Uint8Array(Module.HEAPU8.buffer, dataPtr, bufSize);
    dataOnHeap.set(new Uint8Array(buffer))
    
    worker.onerror = function (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
    
    worker.onmessage = function (event) {
        console.log('result: \ncall id: ' + event.data.callbackId + '.\n response data: ');
    
        const arr = new Uint8Array(event.data.data, length=bufSize);
        console.log(arr); // output is correct
    
        Module._free(dataOnHeap.byteOffset);
    };
    
    const clientMessage = {
        callbackId: 1,
        funcName: 'TestMemory',
        data: dataOnHeap
    };
    worker.postMessage(clientMessage);
    
    //Module._free(dataPtr);
}
```

C++

```
extern "C" EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE void TestMemory(unsigned char* data, size_t size)
{
    std::cout << "TestMemory begin" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "size: " << size << std::endl;

    std::cout << "data: ";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << static_cast<int>(*(data + i)) << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    // modify test
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        *(data + i) = *(data + i) / 2;
    }

    emscripten_worker_respond(reinterpret_cast<char* >(data), size);

    //free(data);
    std::cout << "TestMemory end" << std::endl;
}
```

Image from my canvas takes 1.4MB. Every time I click, the browser memory usage grows, according to ProcessExplorer.

Where I should release memory and how?
How do I release memory correctly?

Thanks